# Call redux-connected component from React using ref

Tags: reactjs, redux, ref

Trying to make a call to component's function from its parent using ref. The component is connected to Redux. Using React ^16. Says that: `TypeError: this.usersTable.getWrappedInstance is not a function`. See code sample below:

```
export default class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.usersTable = React.createRef()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button"
                        onClick={this.usersTable.getWrappedInstance().onAddUser}>ADD NEW USER</button>

                <UsersTable onRef={node => this.usersTable = node} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class UsersTable extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRef(this)
    }

    onAddUser = () => {
        // DO SMTH
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(UsersTable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.usersTable.getWrappedInstance()` is eagerly evaluated on render before `usersTable` ref was assigned.

Refs are mixed up. It's either `React.createRef()` or custom `onRef`, not both. The latter wouldn't need `getWrappedInstance()` but requires props to be passed to wrapped component with mapping functions.

In case `React.createRef()` is used, it's:

```
usersTable = React.createRef();

onButtonClick = () => {
  this.usersTable.current.getWrappedInstance().onAddUser();
}    

...

<button type="button" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
  ADD NEW USER
</button>

<UsersTable ref={this.usersTable} />
```